# ":h command" doesn't work with some commads. How to deal with such cases?

Tags: help-system

When it comes to some commands, getting help is hard. For example, the `display` command.

I know I can use, for example, `set display=truncate` or `set display=lastline`, but when I use `:h display` to read about other values (I don't really know whether they exist), Vim shows me something completely different:

```
-display {display}  Run vim on {display}        *-display*
```

And if try to use `:h set display`, it shows me an error message.

How to deal with such cases?

Comment: That's a good link. This section of Vim's help was added by Christian Brabandt afterward to capture much of the same information: `:h help-summary`

Comment: Thanks. So `display` is an option and options should be enclosed in single quotes. `:h 'display'` works fine.

Comment: Yep. That's right.